# Can we open an activity in pop up window

Tags: android, popup

I'm working on an app, in that i create a class for calender view. Now I want to open that calender activity as a pop up, I don't know how to create popup actually, so I do google and got following code, but that code open only the ui of the calender class. So can anybody tell me how can I do this?

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater 
                 = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
                  .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
                View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_calendar_view, null);  
                         final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                           popupView, 
                           android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
                                 android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                         popupWindow.setWidth(200);
                         popupWindow.setHeight(500);
                        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(b, 500, 30);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: add android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog in manifest file of that activty

Answer (score 2):

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog`

In your Manifest File, in activity block of your class name add the above statement

Comment: if I add above statement in startup class blocks then that class open as popup but not required class

Comment: try adding in activity, using setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog)

Comment: In manifest file add it in the activity block of which class you want to see pop up, don't add in the main / launcher activity, your adding in launcher activity that's why the startup  screen is becoming pop up